# JMeter flow control

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

could anyone suggest a good approach for controlling requests flow in JMeter. Here is the problem statement:

Test Plan:

- Transaction Controller 'Homepage'

  - request 1
  - request 2
  - request 3
- Transaction Controller 'News'

  - request 1
  - request 2
- Transaction Controller 'Results'

  - request 1
  - request 2

What I need is to create controller, that will do following:
1) after 'Homepage' is done 50% users will end test, 20% will go to 'News' and 30% will go to 'Results'.
2) after 'News' is done 80% will go to 'Results' and 20% will go to 'News' again.

the possible solution, as for me, is to create complecated 'If controllers' that check something like:

```
random_value >= 50%
```

and run needed controller

but that seems to be a bit tricky, may be there is a plugin/step that was designed for such things? Or may be I could use some script for flow controlling, like:

```
if(random_value >= 50%) {
   runner.runController("News") 
} else {
   runner.runController("Results") 
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need the throughput controller: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller
To end a test, you can use a test action sampler.

Answer (score 0):

I also would start using Throughput Controller.
The following structure should go very close to the behaviour you need.

- Transaction Ctrl 'Homepage'
- Throughput Ctrl 'Results (weight 30)
- - Module Controller 'Results'
- Throughput Ctrl 'Otherwise' (weight 20)
- - simple controller
- - - Module Controller 'News'
- - - Throughput Ctrl 'News2' (weight 20)
- - - - Module Controller 'News'
- - - Throughput Ctrl 'Results2' (weight 80)
- - - - Module Controller 'Results'
- Transaction Ctrl exit

Please note that this structure allows some user to flow through each leave of the tree, because each Throughput controller is evaluated independently from the other.

Obviously I did not tried it, but I think it is a good approximation with a reasonable effort.

Comment: with that approach test will not choose only one variant. It will just execute each step with certain probability. If there were a possibility to add exit step, this will not be a problem. But I don't know how to dio that...

Comment: update to previous post - I just checked [BeanShell_Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) and it seems to be a solution for emulate user exit (see SampleResult.setStopThread example)

Comment: @abdgirk <br>yes, that is what I said in my explaination